# How to set focus for Tkinter widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple Python + Tkinter application that displays a list of 10 items:

```
import Tkinter, ttk
list = ttk.Treeview( Tkinter.Tk() )
list.pack( fill = Tkinter.BOTH, expand = 1 )
items = [ list.insert( '', 'end', text = str( i ) ) for i in range( 10 ) ]
list.selection_set( items[ 0 ] )
list.focus_set() # This is not working - list has no focus :(
Tkinter.mainloop()
```

Is it possible to modify it so after application starts, list will have focus and i can move selection via up and down arrows? After app starts, app's window has focus, but i can't move selection with arrows until i click list with mouse :(. I tried different combinations of `focus_set()` and `focus_force()`, but it's not working.

Checked with Python 2.7 on Windows 7, OSX 10.7 and Ubuntu 12.04

**UPDATE**

If "Treeview" is changed to some other widget, for example to "Button", the focus is working. So it's seems that i set focus for Treeview somehow incorrectly.

Comment: I've been trying to get this working too, and I'm not sure you can; looks like the function is broken. There's a few other posts out there, and no one has ever found the solution.

Comment: @TankorSmash I don't think a function is broken: Tk/Tkinter is decades old, so it's definitely i'm doing something wrong :)

Comment: Heh, you'd think eh? I subclassed the Treeview, on `__init__` I called `focus_set` then called `focus_get` right after, and it returned None, suggesting nothing changed, even with `takefocus` set to `1`. -- Even edited the Tkinter code, right after `self.tk.call('focus', self._w)` is called, I check to see if the widget `focus_has` and it's still `None`. It's possible that the mainloop has to set something in order for focus to change, but I doubt it.

Comment: I just checked, and the widget is receiving input, it's just not using it to move the selection, so maybe you could just write that yourself? If `<keyDown>` move selection `-1` kind of thing. That's the best I can figure, beyond moving the mouse with win32 and clicking, then moving the mouse back to starting pos

Comment: @TankorSmash if i click widget, it will get focus and will react on keys. So it's not a keybinding issue - it's keyboard focus issue.

Comment: My understanding of TreeView isn't good at all, but take a look at the code I wrote, you'll see that on creation, the widget _is_ getting focus, I guess there's just a few different parts to it, and the wrong one is getting focus. http://pastebin.com/r5MfKqZp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution at last - seems that `Treeview` widget need to be set focus two times: first for the widget itself, and second for an item:

```
list.selection_set( items[ 0 ] )
list.focus_set()
list.focus( items[ 0 ] ) # this fixes a problem.
```